# Poisson Process RAID disk failure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have the following question i am working on :

- Assume that the time it takes before a hard disk drive crashes is
  exponentially distributed with a mean of 5 years. Consider a RAID
  system consisting of 100 hard disk drives. Show that the probability
  that one of the disks crashes within a month is more than 80% and
  within a day more than 5%.

I am aware that i have to put what i have attempted but in reality i have made lots illogical  attempts to solve the question but can't. I am just confused as to what lambda and t is I will appreciate an explanatory text of the different variables and how they will fit into the poisson formula

Comment: @Tyler if the time between events is exponentially distributed, the number of events in a certain time period has poisson distribution.

Comment: The mean failure rate, $\lambda$, is 1 per 5 years, or $\frac{1\ \textrm{failure}}{5\ \textrm{years}}$. Convert this rate to "failures per month". Now use it in your Poisson distribution.

Comment: @Arkamis : You neglected the fact that there are 100 disks.

Answer (score 0):

The rate is $\lambda = 100\times \dfrac 1 {5\text{ years}} = 20\text{ per year} = \dfrac{20}{12} \text{ per month} = \dfrac 5 3 \text{ per month}$.

The probability that the number of occurrences in a month is $0$ is therefore
$$
\frac{(5/3)^0 e^{-5/3}}{0!} \approx 0.1888756.
$$

Proceed similarly for a period of one day.